# Android Long Running Service and database

Tags: android, android-service, android-activity

I am working on a program which consists of two parts

**Service component** will read various system features (CPU usage, RAM usage, Number of Running Tasks, Messages Sent, Calls Made etc) every pre determined time interval lets say 15 minutes. And save these readings/data in a database.

**Activity component** will read the data from SQL database file and process the information.

My Questions are

1. What kind of service do I have to create that will stay alive forever until stopped by the activity it should also automatically restart after system reboot?
2. Has anyone got an example of service writing data to database?
3. Can I invoke the parent activity from the service?

Comment: oh, you seriously need to accept some answers before somebody will bother reading your question

Comment: I only got the permission to mark answers few days ago. Can you please direct me to my question where I haven't accepted a correct answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/777593/khurram-majeed?tab=questions&sort=newest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a fairly standard `Service`. Read up on the [`Service` lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Answers:

1. Any service will do. You'll need a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent to start the service at boot.
2. `Service` objects are `Context` objects, so you can do anything with a SQLite database that you could do from an `Activity`. No difference.
3. Define "invoke" and "parent activity". You can start an `Activity` from the service via the standard `startActivity()` method from `Context`. If you start the `Service` from the `BroadcastReceiver` at boot, it's an independent service not connected to any `Activity` so there is no parent `Activity`.

Note also that a `Service` may not be absolutely necessary for your stated intent. If you're only doing things that infrequently, you may be able to get by with an `AlarmManager` alarm. That way you're not leaving a `Service` running -- and consuming resources -- for something you're only processing every 15 minutes.

Comment: Parent-activity is the activity component of my program it will start the service... Based on your comments can I assume that I can start my activity automatically after a certain interval via AlarmManager.. I have to read various features from System.. Is it possible to do all that from activity without having ANR (Application Not Responding) error?

Comment: Yes, `AlarmManager` is capable of starting anything. And whether you get an ANR has nothing to do with how you implement the launching of the `Service`. The `Service` runs in the same process and in the main thread of any `Activity`. If you are getting ANRs because of the `Service` processing, you'll need to break that processing out into a different `Thread`.